# Transparent blurry background

Tags: jquery, css, primefaces

im working on a webapp using jsf with primefaces.

heres some of my css that makes my dialogs white transparent:

```
.ui-dialog, .ui-dialog-footer {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: transparent\9;
    background: rgba(255,255, 255, 0.6);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#66000000,
        endColorstr=#66000000);
    zoom: 1;
    border: none;
    color: black !important;
}
```

now that looks like this:

http://fs5.directupload.net/images/151201/2tutzmwh.png (seems i dont have enough points to share that pic in the editor xD

what i wanna do is make the background (only behind the dialog) blurry, if possible cross browser compatible ;) jquery allowed...

```
filter: blurry(10px);
```

didnt do the trick for me... consider the dialogs are overlays

any help appreciated

thanks

Comment: Why did you not add a css and/or jquery tag? And it kind of is **not** PrimeFaces, dialog (does it work with a plain div?) and totally not blur related (look at that tag description)... Please improve your tagging to increase the chance of getting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the plugin http://blurjs.com **blur.js**

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/blur.js"></script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#bg').blurjs({
        source: 'body',
        radius: 30,
        overlay: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)'
    });
});
```

Please try it, it is not tested.

Comment: Please edit your post, link is not working. And keep in mind that PrimeFaces alread contains the latest 1.x version of jquery. So adding a 2.0 not be trivial (need to run it in no conflict mode most likely)

Comment: didnt want to have to do it with a jquery plugin... for the moment, ill just not implement the blurry dialogs